# Use pretrained embedding in Spanish with Torchtext

Tags: nlp, deep-learning, pytorch, word-embedding, torchtext

I am using Torchtext in an NLP project. I have a pretrained embedding in my system, which I'd like to use. Therefore, I tried:

```
my_field.vocab.load_vectors(my_path)
```

But, apparently, this only accepts the names of a short list of pre-accepted embeddings, for some reason. In particular, I get this error:

```
Got string input vector "my_path", but allowed pretrained vectors are ['charngram.100d', 'fasttext.en.300d', ..., 'glove.6B.300d']
```

I found some [people with similar problems](https://github.com/pytorch/text/issues/201), but the solutions I can find so far are "change Torchtext source code", which I would rather avoid if at all possible.

Is there any other way in which I can work with my pretrained embedding? A solution that allows to use another Spanish pretrained embedding is acceptable.

Some people seem to think it is not clear what I am asking. So, if the title and final question are not enough: "I need help using a pre-trained Spanish word-embedding in Torchtext".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out there is a relatively simple way to do this without changing Torchtext's source code. Inspiration from this [Github thread](https://github.com/pytorch/text/issues/30).

**1. Create numpy word-vector tensor**

You need to load your embedding so you end up with a numpy array with dimensions (number_of_words, word_vector_length):

my_vecs_array[word_index] should return your corresponding word vector.

IMPORTANT. The indices (word_index) for this array array MUST be taken from Torchtext's word-to-index dictionary (field.vocab.stoi). Otherwise Torchtext will point to the wrong vectors!

Don't forget to convert to tensor:

```
my_vecs_tensor = torch.from_numpy(my_vecs_array)
```

**2. Load array to Torchtext**

I don't think this step is really necessary because of the next one, but it allows to have the Torchtext field with both the dictionary and vectors in one place.

```
my_field.vocab.set_vectors(my_field.vocab.stoi, my_vecs_tensor, word_vectors_length)
```

**3. Pass weights to model**

In your model you will declare the embedding like this:

```
my_embedding = toch.nn.Embedding(vocab_len, word_vect_len)
```

Then you can load your weights using:

```
my_embedding.weight = torch.nn.Parameter(my_field.vocab.vectors, requires_grad=False)
```

Use requires_grad=True if you want to train the embedding, use False if you want to freeze it.

EDIT: It looks like there is [another way](https://www.innoq.com/en/blog/handling-german-text-with-torchtext/) that looks a bit easier! The improvement is that apparently you can pass the pre-trained word vectors directly during the vocabulary-building step, so that takes care of steps 1-2 here.

Comment: Not sure if this was possible when this answer was written, but you can also use the Embedding class method [from_pretrained](https://pytorch.org/docs/1.0.0/nn.html#torch.nn.Embedding.from_pretrained) to do this.

Comment: I'm not sure either. I think using from_pretrained would make the last two steps a bit cleaner. Thanks for the contribution :)